# sox with MP3 on Heroku

Tags: heroku, sox, libsox

My app uses sox to apply some effects to an audio file on a Heroku dyno.

I added `sox`, `libsox-fmt-mp3` and `libsox-fmt-all` to `Aptfile` using the APT buildpack. Sox is installed but MP3 files are still not working. `sox -h` tells me that there is no MP3 support installed.

I also tried these buildpacks but MP3 files are still not working:

- https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/lepinsk/heroku-buildpack-sox
- https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/dennisdevulder/heroku-buildpack-sox-with-mp3

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Having the same exact issue. Hasn't figured out yet how to get it working. However I ended up using this buildpack https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git I could get accomplished what I needed from sox with ffmpeg